# How to match text between double slashes but not url?

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace double slashes in a wiki markup with something else (double slashes stands for italic text).

How can I match italic text, without URLs?

This regexp is for a text where are no URLs: `//(.*?)//`

Problem appears when there is a text like:

```
//italic text// and this is only http://some.url/somewhere and this is //another italic text// yeah
```

I'm using Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?<!:)//(.+?)//
```

It requires that `//` does not have `:` in front of it. This would catch most URL forms.

Also, I changed your `(.*?)` to `(.+?)` - it requires at least 1 character between `//` to be valid - your code would allow `////`.

Comment: `(?<!https?:)` could reduce the number of false positives.

Comment: @sp00m: what about `ssh://` or `git://`?

Comment: This online tester http://regexpal.com/ doesn't know lookbehind, but this one does - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ .

Comment: @mvp Would reduce them too.